# CSS Font family not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

Hey I have the following code in a scss file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'tr-icon';
    src:url('../fonts/tr-icon.eot?88d087');
    src:url('../fonts/tr-icon.eot?#iefix88d087') format('embedded-opentype') ,
        url('../fonts/tr-icon.ttf?88d087') format('truetype') ,
        url('../fonts/tr-icon.woff?88d087') format('woff') ,
        url('../fonts/tr-icon.svg?88d087#trends') format('svg') ;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
[class^="tr-icon-"], [class*=" tr-icon-"] {
    font-family: 'tr-icon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

It is rejected by Firefox with the following error :

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "tr-icon" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0)
```

I just can't get it working. I tried different work-around as https://jamie.curle.io/posts/firefox-font-rejected-by-sanitzer/ or https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2121 but nothing seems to work... Any other idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have tried this?

removed the query string at the end of each line?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'tr-icon';
    src:url('../fonts/tr-icon.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/tr-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype') ,
        url('../fonts/tr-icon.ttf') format('truetype') ,
        url('../fonts/tr-icon.woff') format('woff') ,
        url('../fonts/tr-icon.svg#trends') format('svg') ;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Because of the query string at the end of each url/path is te reason why your font is rejected by sanitizer.

Comment: Yes, I got exactly the same error without the query string
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "tr-icon" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: fonts/tr-icon.eot

Comment: this means that your css pre-processor still ad those strings. have you moved the font-face part out of the scss part?

Comment: Oh dear, I did it indeed, but I move into the css file some scss code not being recognized and it messed up everything. It is working now :)

Comment: Great,trying to find this solution since 2 days.. this resolved the issue. i don't understand why the hell this solution not there on Font awesome support website. why do they created this bug?